# Set div height to the same as width for all elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set the height to match the width for all containers of the same class.

I have a number of images of various sizes across my site. I would like each image's div container to have the same height as its own width.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width:600px">
    <img src="image1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper" style="width:400px">
    <img src="image2.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper" style="width:200px">
    <img src="image3.jpg">
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
    border-radius: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I originally attempted the following:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
    container.style.height = getComputedStyle(wrapper).width;
} );
```

This solution worked, except it only affected the first occurrence of each wrapper.

I also tried adapting another example I've found on StackOverflow (sorry can't find the link), to no avail:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wrapper').each(function() {
        var maxWidth = 100;    // Max width for the image
        var maxHeight = 100;    // Max height for the image
        var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
        var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
        var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

        // Check if the current width is larger than the max
        if(width > maxWidth) {
            ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
            $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }

        // Check if current height is larger than max
        if(height > maxHeight) {
            ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
            $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JSFiddle (HTML + CSS): https://jsfiddle.net/h2xnqrL9/

Comment: In your example that work's but only the first class ..  You could try a `.each` --> `$('.wapper').each(function(i, obj) {`

Comment: Thank you all so much for your responses.

I ended up using Carlos' answer as I feel that it was the most elegant solution to my problem. However, they all worked perfectly and I learnt a lot in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's no need for Javascript here.

You can use a trick to set any container height to it's width:

```css
.wrapper {position:relative;}
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%; /*trick here*/
}
.wrapper img {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Any padding-top percentage value is relative to the parent container's width. 100% means it will be a square, 50% would give it half it's width.

It's a great trick when you're playing with image ratios ;)

I forked your jsfiddle with the extra code and added an outline so you could see the square container

https://jsfiddle.net/tLw354jm/2/

EDIT: Specification here https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-padding

Answer (score 3):

The reason it didn't work for your first solution is because `document.querySelector(".wrapper")` only returns the first match. What you want to do is get all the matches, in which case you can use `document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper")` and then loop over the elements.

With jQuery, you can do this using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".wrapper").each(function (index, divElem) {
    divElem.style.height = divElem.style.width;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".wrapper").each(function() {
    $(this).css('height', $(this).css('width'))
  })
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper" style="width:600px">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/b0b0b0/000000.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper" style="width:400px">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/b0b0b0/000000.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper" style="width:200px">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/b0b0b0/000000.jpg">
</div>
```